# Simple Merge / Purge with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, merge, purge

I have four Excel files that contain email addresses. I need to find out how many unique addresses are in the first three, but not in the fourth.

What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can copy all of the data into one sheet, you can use the 'remove duplicates' (under **Data**) to find unique addresses. If you colour-code the entries from each file first, you'll be able to tell which came from where, and which ones are left over.

**Edit:**

If you used background colours to code the entries, you can use [this function](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/sum-count-cells-by-color.htm) to count the entries.

If you coloured the font, you can use [this function](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/Sort.htm), taking care to replace 'Interior' with 'Font' as noted in the explanation at the top.

Comment: Thanks. That takes care of the "merge" part. Is there a way to find out how many entries have a certain color? Can I sort by color?